# Fastest way to export a 2d matrix to a triples format CSV file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I want to convert a 2d matrix, for example:

```
10  2
3   5
```

to a (row,col,value) CSV file, for example:

```
1,1,10
1,2,2
2,1,3
2,2,5
```

is it possible to do it in a single Matlab command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a way with a single command, but try the following code:

```
[i1,i2] = ind2sub(size(A),1:numel(A));
csvwrite('test.csv',[i2',i1',reshape(A',numel(A),1)]);
```

The output is:

```
type test.csv

1,1,10
1,2,2
2,1,3
2,2,5
```

Comment: +1 That was the approach I was typing, just before I saw your answer :-)

Comment: Sorry for that. Next time I wait a few second longer. ;)

Comment: not a single instruction but compact and fast enough, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `A` to be the input matrix, two approaches can be suggested here.

**[`fprintf`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)** based solution -

```
output_file = 'data.txt'; %// Edit if needed to be saved to a different path
At = A.';  %//'
[y,x] = ndgrid(1:size(At,1),1:size(At,2));
fid = fopen(output_file, 'w+');
for ii=1:numel(At)
    fprintf(fid, '%d,%d,%d\n',x(ii),y(ii),At(ii));
end
fclose(fid);
```

---

**[`dlmwrite`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html)** based approach -

```
At = A.';  %//'
[y,x] = ndgrid(1:size(At,1),1:size(At,2));
dlmwrite(output_file,[x(:) y(:) At(:)]);
```

**Some quick tests** seem to suggest that `fprintf` performs better across varying input datasizes.

Comment: +1 for the second approach. `csvwrite` would work too

Comment: @LuisMendo Well if you look into the source code of `csvwrite`, it calls `dlmwrite`. So `dlmwrite` actually saves one function call, which is good I think.

Comment: @Divakar Nice to know about `csvwrite` and `dlmwrite`.

Comment: @Nemesis yeah it was a good exercise to look for such tools, not that I use them often :)