# Faster way to save in .txt format in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to save a huge matrix `A` in Matlab in `.txt` format (without comma and semicolon). The matrix `A` is generated at each iteration of a loop. At the moment I'm using `dlmwrite` to save but it is very very slow, e.g.

```
for h=1:100
    A=randn(1000000,1000);
    dlmwrite(sprintf('B%d.txt',h), A, ' ')
end
```

Could you suggest a faster way that gives exactly the same output?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929161/fastest-way-to-export-a-2d-matrix-to-a-triples-format-csv-file-in-matlab) helps?

Comment: No, it is even slower

Comment: If the `fprintf` method is still too slow, you've hit the disk write limit.

Comment: At each iteration you are writing 1000M of doubles, represented with strings, 7 chars(per my test) long each with spaces, so 8 chars. So you are attempting to write around 100x8Gbyte data. Are you sure it is slow, or it is just too big?